# Apply Templates in Microsoft Word

Tags: msword

I usually use TeX to write my documents, but say for some reason I want to use Word Document (e.g. sending the document to a friend for editing). So is it possible to apply templates in Microsoft Word?

Comment: This seems to be off-topic (it's about Word, not TeX). If I were not a mod I've vote to close

Comment: I thought so, but didn't really find another place to ask. Tell me where to ask this and I will close it myself :-)

Comment: @Rafid: What exactly do you want to know? How to format a Word document to be like a LaTeX document?  If so you could go here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8308/2693

Comment: @Rafid Word has its own templating system see http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/authors_journals.html#sect2 for some examples.

Comment: @Alan, thanks, it seems that @Yiannis answered my question. What I want to know is whether Word itself has templating system and whether it is to apply templates for it like it is for LaTeX. For example, although I am using LaTeX, if for one reason, I have to use Word one day, will it be easy for me to apply templates from different conferences/journals?

Comment: No, I am just asking about templates in Microsoft Word and @Yiannis already answered me. @Yiannis, could you please put your comment as an answer so that I mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word has its own templating system see http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/authors/authors_journals.html#sect2 for some examples.