# Is there a CSS file to make my Webpage "look like" latex ouput

Tags: html

In a similar vein to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/make-ms-word-document-look-like-it-has-been-typeset-in-latex), can I make my web page look like is was typeset in latex. I know it won't be possible to replicate the latex look exactly.

Is there a CSS file which will control typefaces/font-sizes/margins etc to give the unmistakable latex "look"? (as far as practicable)

The layout would probably have to be single column, as a HTML page can scroll indefinitely. So things like page breaks/page-numbers might be irrelevant in this context.

I know I could simply replace my HTML file with links to latex set PDFs, but that is not want I want to do.

I'm already using mathJax for my equations. I guess what I am really looking for are appropriate CSS settings for the common tags `<body>,<h1>,<h2>,<p>,<strong>` etc, etc.

Comment: http://webtypography.net/ is a good start on this topic in general.

Comment: I'd say this question is off-topic here, as it's not to do with anything TeX or related tools can do.

Comment: (I should add that if I were not a mod I'd vote to close.)

Comment: If the similar question about achieving the latex look in MSWord was not off-topic, I don't see how this one is. Also, I would call a latex "formatting" CSS file, a TeX related tool.

Comment: I am sorry, but you are never going to make your web page look like latex output in my lynx browser :)

Comment: @Ken: arguing that "this question should stay because that question did" is shaky ground at best.  That question was marginal.  Possibly many people _did_ vote for its closure but it didn't get quite enough to close it.

Comment: You can apply some of the suggestions from the Word question. Use CSS3 Web fonts to load Latin Modern, measure the text width, set headers to bold Latin Modern etc.

Comment: Possibly you can run `tex4ht` on a LaTeX document. This will produce an `html` and a `css` (both quite dirty), which you might be able to adapt for your use. Or, if writing in TeX is an option at all, you can choose to use `tex4ht` straight.

Comment: Not LaTeX style, but I have created [gutenweb](http://lamarciana.github.io/gutenweb/), a CSS file focused on typographical aspects to quick creation of documents.

Comment: Shouldn’t this question have been moved to Stack Overflow instead?

Comment: As a starter you can get the Computer Modern fonts for your website from http://checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/. In addition here somebody used LaTeX fonts for a wordpress theme: https://guillaumepaumier.com/project/fumseck/