# Visual comparison between LaTeX and Word output (hyphenation, typesetting, ligatures etc)

Tags: msword, latex-misc

I really want to convince my friends and family that LaTeX is the choice for them when it comes to formatting and creating beautiful documents. I am aware of the major advantages that come with using LaTeX but some are not convinced. Can someone please provide a side by side comparison of a Word document (or something of the sort) and a LaTeX document that shows the obvious and subtle differences between the two? I want people to look at it and say "Ahhh, I see it, there's a major difference".

Comment: Do you require comparisons between mathematical texts as well?

Comment: @KevinC Anything that shows LaTeX is superior in quality and presentation will do!

Comment: possible duplicate [How to convert TeX-illiterate coworkers to LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102878/15717) and [Why should I use LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1756/15717)

Comment: @texenthusiast I have looked at those links (edit: before) but I feel that a more visual example will convince my friends and family more easily. Seeing the difference is better than reading the difference, in my opinion.

Comment: So you are looking for [How can I explain the meaning of LaTeX to my gramma](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94889/how-can-i-explain-the-meaning-of-latex-to-my-grandma). :)

Comment: @Fran haha no! Explaining LaTeX I can do but to show a side by side comparison that says "Look at this text in Word and look at this text in LaTeX, see the difference? Notice, this and that?" I tried explaining to one of my teachers that LaTeX was the way to go when it came to formatting important documents but he was unconvinced because to him, a word document and LaTeX produced document looked the same, even though they were not. That's the motivation behind the question. For someone not familiar to look and _see_ the difference.

Comment: I agree with your edit- if it does get closed, I for one will vote to re-open :)

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://nitens.org/taraborelli/latex).

Comment: This questions simply assumes at the outset that there is such a difference. Sure, by using the _default_ settings in LaTeX and MSWord, the documents will look very different. But with some work, any MSWord document can look like any LaTeX document, and vice versa. I also see no use in 'convincing your friends and family' that they should use LaTeX. They should use LaTeX if there are things they cannot do in Word or requires an unreasonable amount of effort to do. Otherwise, let Word users be Word users. It's sufficient for most people.

Comment: @Sverre This is the exact point of my friends said to me but you cannot do it as easily. For you to implement the style and default settings of LaTeX, you would have to be very skilled in Word, in my opinion. Also, wouldn't you want your friends and family to have the same quality of documents as you do? For example, their CV to look as professional as yours (without the work put in) or their essay or their report? Sure, you aren't going to use LaTeX for something quick and dirty but surely for essays, reports and CV's.

Comment: @gekkostate I think we need to agree to disagree. I don't think LaTeX documents by themselves have a higher quality or look more professional. It's all about how you yourself format your documents, LaTeX or Word. If you're not in academia or publishing, I see little use in learning LaTeX.

Comment: All what is said here in this thread is concerned to TeX, no to LaTeX. The title of the document shown in the first answer is very confusing: There is a version 3.1415926 of *TeX* but pdfLaTeX is mentioned here. This is absurd.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I find the comparison posted http://www.rtznet.nl/zink/latex.php?lang=en to be very effective- here's a visual

[image: screenshot]

If the visual isn't enough, check out the analysis!

[image]

Where IWS is the inter-word spacing and SD, stands for Standard Deviation, a measure of the variability of IWS (as computed by the square root of the average square deviation from the mean IWS). A lower value indicates less variability and therefore more regularity.

Comment: Could please provide the significance of low SD of IWS?

Comment: @gekkostate in general, a low standard deviation tells us that the data points are close to the mean... in this context, the inter word spacing having a low standard deviation tells us that the general value of the inter word spacing is fairly consistent- we don't have words that are too close together, nor too far away. Just as in [Goldilocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_the_Three_Bears) `pdflatex` gets it just right :)

Comment: @gekkostate It would be interesting to remove the red marks and labels to have someone pick the best-looking of the three settings -- a sort of blind test.  Of course, this might backfire if the MS Word or InDesign typesettings are chosen...

Comment: @HenryDeYoung I think If I had a word document with tables and math equations and then made the same one in LaTeX then the difference would be easily noticeable.

Comment: I would be interesting to have the very same comparison for slightly different line widths - it _might_ be that they just picked one that makes InDesign look bad. (I guess Word is hopeless for this narrow line width.)

Comment: However effective, this doesn't look like the result of a fair comparison to me – the pdftex sample has most certainly been hand-tweaked with `\emergencystretch`, probably also adjusted `\fontdimen`s, maybe even some negative spacing (look at the line beginning with "warehouses"); I am fairly sure that the Indesign sample could be optimised in the same way (esp. considering that Indesign's paragraph builder is based on that of TeX).

Comment: @HendrikVogt a more general purpose objection than "they cherry picked the specific width to make tex end up doing much better than the competition" would be noting that in the typical use case with normal page widths there's no need to do a hyphenation vs excess IWS tradeoff to try and get a good result with any of the tools.

Comment: @Robert -- i don't think tweaking `\emergencystretch` could have this result, since `\emergencystretch` acts only on entire paragraphs, forcing an extra pass to "scale down the badnesses so that large infinities are indistinguishable from smaller ones" (texbook, p.107).  since none of the interword spaces are excessive, per the table, it shouldn't have been needed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton But for tex, an interword space of 9pt _is_ already excessive -- with a 12pt font, the maximum (fontdimen 3+4) would usually be about 6pt (for cmr) or 5pt (for fonts installed with `fontinst`). Anyway, I've tried to reproduce the sample, and I think this indeed corroborates my suspicions: [see PDF](http://scribd.com/doc/144579018/Test), which I think is close enough.

Comment: @Robert -- okay, fair enough.  thanks for details.  (of course, narrow columns are always a beast.  but sometimes there just isn't any reasonable alternative.)

Comment: And adding microtype, the LaTeX output would have been even more superior. That is what I like with LaTeX: it is so simple to produce nice text. I use Word a lot, but even if I tinker with the text for hours, I am not able to get it right. Word 2010 is better than 2007, but still lacking a lot. And yes: I have used all the advanced features of Word since version 1.1. Still Word 2010 has not catched up with WordPerfect 5.1 when it comes to hyphenated, justified text. Word has lot of strenght, but do not bother to set justified text. Use ragged right, and manual hyphenation.

Comment: I'll note that this answer does not use ligature in Word output, which is pointed out below.

Answer (score 53):

Any single-page text in LaTeX could look very similar to one obtained with a WYSIWYG word processors with the appropriate formatting.

What make a real difference often at the first glance is the lack of **consistency** on this format on a whole big document made with a word processors, even when the user is an expert using predefined styles, against the complete consistence of an structured LaTeX document, even when the user is a novice.

For example, how many unnecessary double paces or blank lines have any big Word document of an average user? This mistakes are hardly noticed and corrected and spoiled the format, but simply does not exist in LaTeX.

In this view also has a high weight the **subtle changes of typography**. As cmhughes pointed, there are some better hyphenation and spacing in LaTeX (that example probably could be improved with the `microtype` package) but you can also compare another details, as kerning and ligatures.

For example, compare this few words between LateX (above) and Abiword: (Sorry, I don't have Word)

[image]

At first glance, for most people there are no differences, but in the word processor there are not ligatures "ff" and "fi", there are a bad kerning in "Fe" and "Ta", but moreover, the kerning is just awful in "AVA". In a large text, hundreds of such details make a big difference that most people notice, although surely they do not know why.

Besides, there a lot of things that you cannot show with a visual comparison, as TikZ diagrams and plots with pgfplots, simply because a word processor is unable to do figures without a third program (that most likely include wrong font types or font sizes).

Comment: I like the commentary at the beginning about not having to worry about layout in same way (+1), but the kerning and ligatures are also a good point...I figured that Word must get this correct, so I just checked it...(Word 2010, Times New Roman)...nope.  Kerning and ligatures are terrible there as well.

Comment: @Fran This is a really nice example because it shows right down to each letter or group of letters where it differs from word and other WYSIWYG editors. Good points!

Comment: Apparently you _can_ adjust kerning in Word: http://word.tips.net/T001130_Changing_Kerning.html (I don't have it installed so I can't check if and how good it works)

Comment: MSWord can do figures and diagrams, usually created in Excel and copy-pasted. But (IMO of course) their look is inferior to PGF/TikZ. Someone should really do visual comparisons on that too. (And I love when my physics professor tries to hand-draw circles in PowerPoint).

Comment: The more recent versions of Word can use kerning, and (with Opentype fonts) automatically insert ligatures, old-style numbers and so forth. I've no doubt that TeX output is superior, but the gap has closed quite a bit in the past 5 years, if users bother to set it up right.

Comment: @PaulStanley, after years using Linux, my ignorance of recent versions of Word is total, while that of the older versions is increasing. Fortunately I was not specific about the word processor because of it.

Comment: @marczellm, but strictly speaking,  Excel or PowerPoint are parts of MSOffice, not of MSWord. These are separate programs, although contents can be linked of OLE objects. The comparison could be them a whole office suite versus your preferred text editor.

Comment: *“For example, how many unnecessary double paces or blank lines have any big Word document of an average user? This mistakes are hardly noticed and corrected and spoiled the format, but simply does not exist in LaTeX.”*  Have you ever taught newcomers to use LaTeX?  I have seen all sorts of such mistakes, including breaking all lines manually with `\\ ` and starting every paragraph with `\paragraph`, not to mention subtler things like `e.g. this` (which plenty of non-novice newcomers still do).  The common mistakes are different, and I think fewer, but let’s not pretend there are none.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I saw also new users in word processors making really stupid mistakes until they learn the basics.  I have not pretended to say (and I have not said) that LaTeX user cannot make any mistake, or that  LaTeX can be used without a steeper learning curve.   But LaTeX was created so the user is responsible of the document structure, not of the format, whereas in WYSYWYG processors is the opposite concept. And that has a cost.

Comment: What the **** is a feline table?

Comment: @Gaussler It is an environment were cats can float to top postions without any penalties. [This](https://www.japantrendshop.com/img/products/6351/6351-1-dinos-oak-relaxing-cat-dining-table-1.jpg) is a feline table.

Comment: @Fran Thanks for the info, hadn’t seen those around before.

Answer (score 22):

I recently have to re-type an entire LaTeX document in Word because the conference organizer only accepts Word documents. The following picture contrasts the two outputs. (It should be pretty easy to tell which one is from LaTeX and which is from Word `:)`)

Besides the lack of hyphenation in Word, which screws up the spacing between words (although I believe that with some effort one might be able to get Word to start hyphenating words), the biggest contrasts are in math fonts, and the spacing between math texts and regular ones. The equation editor in Word (2007 and above) only supports `Cambria Math` font in the math zone. This creates font inconsistencies, unless the same font is also used in the body texts.

[image: word vs latex]

Comment: This is a very nice comparison!

Comment: I am not able to tell at a glance which is LaTeX and which is Word. Your comment about hyphenation suggests that the first one is LaTeX, but frankly the first one is the uglier to me, mostly because of the line break in the mathematics on the first line. (I always consider line breaks in the middle of mathematics to be very ugly indeed. Yes, I am aware that an author can discourage TeX from doing that.)

Comment: Doesn't Word support _any_ opentype math font? I am not sure which text font you are using, but instead of Cambria you can use xits (matches with times), asana (matches with palatino), or LM-math (matches with CM/LM).

Comment: Ok which one is LaTex? Why is LaTex the ugly one?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: The one above the red line is the output of LaTeX, and the one below the red line is output of Word. Hammerite seems to think that the LaTeX output is uglier because of the breaking of a math formula at the end of line 1.

Comment: @Aditya: I'm only using Word 2007. Maybe they have better font support for the newer versions of Word? I've seen elsewhere that with some hacking, you can get word to support other STIX (or some similar spelling) fonts in the math zone. But I never tried it out.

Comment: @Kevin C: I agree with Hammerite the `\infinity}` widow is extremely ugly. (but I see now that the spacing in word is way too big)

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: It's either having the `\infty\}` widow, or an overfull box with `and\; G<\infty\right\}` sticking out in the first line. I chose the former.

Comment: @KevinC: I haven't used it myself, but I have read that Word 2007 supports opentype math fonts. So you should be able to use _any_ opentype math font with Word (the trouble is that right now, there are only three or four opentype math fonts, and Cambria is the most comprehensive of them all).

Comment: I tend to think that in situations like this the least bad thing to do is to put the mathematics in a single-line displayed mathematics environment.

Comment: The 7th line should be enough to distinguish which one was made with Word. Word always is able to hyphenate Words, but not being the default option is rarely used.  IMO this is incomparably worse that  break before the infinity symbol, but moreover this problem cannot   compared with the Word ouput, that behaves differently just because the math font is narrower (i.e, that does not mean a better algorithm to break lines).

Comment: Pandoc offers a way to convert from eg., Tex to Word

Answer (score 22):

The scientist appreciates the subtile beauty of LaTeX, as well as the possibility for version control, which is not possible with Word documents.

Word:

[image]

LaTeX:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

This should be pretty convincing.

[image]

Comment: I had no idea you used `emacs`- is it like `vim`? :)

Comment: This would not convince me of anything.  I wouldn't even know what I was looking at.  I'm seeing some something fancy, with "Word" repeated several times.  This tells me nothing about the more standard type of documents that most people who use WYSIWYG editors are creating.

Comment: @cmhughes: I also use `emacs`. Maybe `vim` is a bit like it?

Comment: @Beska maybe the idea is that in TeX you can make more fancy shapes by words?

Comment: @Ooker simpler: it's a Joke, happy pink heart in tex, sad frown in word, so clearly tex is better. But if people can't take a joke and want to downvote, that's their right:-)

Answer (score 12):

Many of these other examples don’t actually use the full feature set of Microsoft Word, which nowadays includes hyphenation, ligatures, and kerning. So I decided to make a comparison in 2022 where I actually went through those extra steps to make the MS Word output look better. The text (which is from the article [Printing press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing_press) on Wikipedia) is set with Linux Libertine at 11 pt on an A4 sheet with 4 cm left and right margins. The LaTeX version was compiled with LuaLaTeX, `fontspec`, and `microtype`. Here are the results:

#### Microsoft Word:

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### LaTeX (using LuaLaTeX and `microtype`):

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### LibreOffice Writer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Honest opinion by @Gaussler, the original author of this post: Yes, LaTeX is, without a doubt, better. But the difference has become a *lot* smaller than it used to. I’m mainly just happy for the world that there is a program (MS Word) that literally anyone can pick up and use to produce decent results. This fact presents a much greater breakthrough in the history of information exchange than any theoretical results like Knuth’s line breaking algorithm. And in an age where people are more than happy to read articles in a web browser without any hyphenation or text justification, what MS Word outputs will be more than enough for the average user. Maybe we should come down from our ivory tower and give ordinary people a break?

EDIT: Forgot to change `"` into TeX quotation marks. I’m too lazy to change that now.

EDIT: This post is now a community wiki so that anyone can add other visual demonstrations of the same text in other programs (Pages, InDesign, whatever). In order to make the examples easier to compare, it’s best if they are kept in the same resolution, so please use the following method: First export the file to PDF, then use [this online tool](https://pdftoimage.com/) to convert the PDF to a series of JPG images. Then crop the images on local hardware.

EDIT: Here is the LuaTeX source code if anyone wants to check or experiment. I don’t think there is any way to attach a Word document in here, so I’ll leave that out for now. I have deliberately chosen not to wrap the lines in the code to make it easier to copy-paste into word processors with minimal adjustments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,article,english,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec,babel} % Not sure if babel matters in English?
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}

\frenchspacing

\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\noindent
A printing press is a mechanical device for applying pressure to an inked surface resting upon a print medium (such as paper or cloth), thereby transferring the ink. It marked a dramatic improvement on earlier printing methods in which the cloth, paper or other medium was brushed or rubbed repeatedly to achieve the transfer of ink, and accelerated the process. Typically used for texts, the invention and global spread of the printing press was one of the most influential events in the second millennium.

In Germany, around 1440, goldsmith Johannes Gutenberg invented the movable-type printing press, which started the Printing Revolution. Modelled on the design of existing screw presses, a single Renaissance movable-type printing press could produce up to 3,600 pages per workday, compared to forty by hand-printing and a few by hand-copying. Gutenberg's newly devised hand mould made possible the precise and rapid creation of metal movable type in large quantities. His two inventions, the hand mould and the movable-type printing press, together drastically reduced the cost of printing books and other documents in Europe, particularly for shorter print runs.

From Mainz the movable-type printing press spread within several decades to over two hundred cities in a dozen European countries. By 1500, printing presses in operation throughout Western Europe had already produced more than twenty million volumes. In the 16th century, with presses spreading further afield, their output rose tenfold to an estimated 150 to 200 million copies. By the mid-17th century the first printing presses arrived in colonial America in response to the increasing demand for Bibles and other religious literature. The operation of a press became synonymous with the enterprise of printing, and lent its name to a new medium of expression and communication, “the press”.

The arrival of mechanical movable type printing in Europe in the Renaissance introduced the era of mass communication, which permanently altered the structure of society. The relatively unrestricted circulation of information and (revolutionary) ideas transcended borders, captured the masses in the Reformation and threatened the power of political and religious authorities. The sharp increase in literacy broke the monopoly of the literate elite on education and learning and bolstered the emerging middle class. Across Europe, the increasing cultural self-awareness of its peoples led to the rise of proto-nationalism, and accelerated the development of European vernaculars, to the detriment of Latin's status as lingua franca. In the 19th century, the replacement of the hand-operated Gutenberg-style press by steam-powered rotary presses allowed printing on an industrial scale.

\chapter*{History}

\section*{Economic conditions and intellectual climate}

The rapid economic and socio-cultural development of late medieval society in Europe created favorable intellectual and technological conditions for Gutenberg's improved version of the printing press: the entrepreneurial spirit of emerging capitalism increasingly made its impact on medieval modes of production, fostering economic thinking and improving the efficiency of traditional work processes. The sharp rise of medieval learning and literacy amongst the middle class led to an increased demand for books which the time-consuming hand-copying method fell far short of accommodating.

\section*{Technological factors}

Technologies preceding the press that led to the press's invention included: manufacturing of paper, development of ink, woodblock printing, and distribution of eyeglasses. At the same time, a number of medieval products and technological processes had reached a level of maturity which allowed their potential use for printing purposes. Gutenberg took up these far-flung strands, combined them into one complete and functioning system, and perfected the printing process through all its stages by adding a number of inventions and innovations of his own:

The screw press which allowed direct pressure to be applied on a flat plane was already of great antiquity in Gutenberg's time and was used for a wide range of tasks. Introduced in the 1st century AD by the Romans, it was commonly employed in agricultural production for pressing wine grapes and olives (for olive oil), both of which formed an integral part of the Mediterranean and medieval diet. The device was also used from very early on in urban contexts as a cloth press for printing patterns. Gutenberg may have also been inspired by the paper presses which had spread through the German lands since the late 14th century and which worked on the same mechanical principles.

During the Islamic Golden Age, Arab Muslims were printing texts, including passages from the Qur'an, embracing the Chinese craft of paper making, developed it and adopted it widely in the Muslim world, which led to a major increase in the production of manuscript texts. In Egypt during the Fatimid era, the printing technique was adopted reproducing texts on paper strips and supplying them in various copies to meet the demand.

Gutenberg adopted the basic design, thereby mechanizing the printing process. Printing, however, put a demand on the machine quite different from pressing. Gutenberg adapted the construction so that the pressing power exerted by the platen on the paper was now applied both evenly and with the required sudden elasticity. To speed up the printing process, he introduced a movable undertable with a plane surface on which the sheets could be swiftly changed.

The concept of movable type existed prior to 15th century Europe; sporadic evidence that the typographical principle, the idea of creating a text by reusing individual characters, was known and had been cropping up since the 12th century and possibly before (the oldest known application dating back as far as the Phaistos disc). The known examples range from movable type printing in China during the Song dynasty; in Korea during the Goryeo Dynasty, where metal movable-type printing technology was developed in 1234; to Germany (Prüfening inscription) and England (letter tiles) and Italy (Altarpiece of Pellegrino II). However, the various techniques employed (imprinting, punching and assembling individual letters) did not have the refinement and efficiency needed to become widely accepted. Tsuen-Hsuin and Needham, and Briggs and Burke suggest that the movable-type printing in China and Korea was rarely employed.

Gutenberg greatly improved the process by treating typesetting and printing as two separate work steps. A goldsmith by profession, he created his type pieces from a lead-based alloy which suited printing purposes so well that it is still used today. The mass production of metal letters was achieved by his key invention of a special hand mould, the matrix. The Latin alphabet proved to be an enormous advantage in the process because, in contrast to logographic writing systems, it allowed the type-setter to represent any text with a theoretical minimum of only around two dozen different letters.

Another factor conducive to printing arose from the book existing in the format of the codex, which had originated in the Roman period. Considered the most important advance in the history of the book prior to printing itself, the codex had completely replaced the ancient scroll at the onset of the Middle Ages (AD 500). The codex holds considerable practical advantages over the scroll format: it is more convenient to read (by turning pages), more compact, and less costly, and both recto and verso sides could be used for writing or printing, unlike the scroll.

A fourth development was the early success of medieval papermakers at mechanizing paper manufacture. The introduction of water-powered paper mills, the first certain evidence of which dates to 1282, allowed for a massive expansion of production and replaced the laborious handcraft characteristic of both Chinese and Muslim papermaking. Papermaking centres began to multiply in the late 13th century in Italy, reducing the price of paper to one-sixth of parchment and then falling further; papermaking centers reached Germany a century later.

Despite this it appears that the final breakthrough of paper depended just as much on the rapid spread of movable-type printing. It is notable that codices of parchment, which in terms of quality is superior to any other writing material, still had a substantial share in Gutenberg's edition of the 42-line Bible. After much experimentation, Gutenberg managed to overcome the difficulties which traditional water-based inks caused by soaking the paper, and found the formula for an oil-based ink suitable for high-quality printing with metal type.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Excellent work. I’m surprised anyone else bothered to go through the work. `xD`

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Well done!

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis On the other hand, look at the interword spacing in the paragraph right after the heading. I’d say Writer is the worst of them.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Actually, are you sure you turned on hyphenation? Those three line breaks were dashes that already existed in the text.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Very strange indeed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137905/discussion-between-apoorv-potnis-and-gaussler).

Comment: Something went wrong with the second output. Although the smart quotes are entered correctly in the source code, in the output they point in the wrong direction.

Comment: @user202729 I know, that was a mistake, as remarked above. What I didn’t remark was that I corrected it in the source code. However, I decided that the detail was so minor that I didn’t want to go through the work of updating the images over it. `;-)`

Answer (score 11):

don't be religious! It's only typesetting. :)

People, which has not be programmed before, may be shocked if they see an emacs with auctex and at least a compile run. It's also with TeXShop the case!

However, the result can be impressive (but it is also possible to generate a poor quality with TeX).

If you have a lot of very different font types within a document (like this example: [UTF8 for listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110020/utf8-for-listings)), it is definitly more easy to use OpenOffice or Word.

LaTeX has the main focus for structured documents (also letters). Well, I has used LaTeX for animations in presentation and also included videos in a PDF, but these are very advanced features, which are especially for friends with an average knowledge of programming totally out of scope.

Comment: 'it's only typesetting'!!! we're pretty obsessed with it on this site :)

Comment: Agreed. LaTeX really shines in producing long, highly structured documents. The average user of a word-processing program will gain very little advantage from learning LaTeX if all they tend to produce is short (1-2 page) documents.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that both are more than adequate but Latex was designed being a stickler for the details and more thought given to minutae. That and rendering formulae. It was developed at a time where the difference was much more stark. That is why it took off in publishing / math and science communities. Over time they will catch up but the history is not one of excellence, but one of utility and good enough to get out the door. With one of the examples above I couldn't tell which was better, the first spacing / indentation algorithm example I definitely noticed and some of the kerning examples illustrate the point. You don't notice it until you really look, good enough to get out the door.