# Can I locally switch to a 'greedy' justification algorithm?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithms

I'm not optimistic about this since this is a core part of TeX's algorithm, but is there any way to switch to a 'greedy' justification algorithm?  That is, instead of working on the paragraph as a whole and optimizing word spacing, fit as much as you can onto one line, hyphenating if necessary, justify, and then move to the next line.

Comment: no​​​​​​​​​​​:)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What's that I'm always hearing about you and one-word answers? `;)` Although, in this case, I think a one-word answer is sufficient—but I still have hope! …sort of!

Comment: However if you described the end effect that you want to achieve it may be possible to tune the paragraph breaking parameters to get something closer to what you want (cf `\sloppy`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm creating a table that compares TeX's default behavior with other solutions'—such as Word.

Comment: Something like this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110133/ while avoiding simply `\includegraphics`.

Comment: The only fair thing to do in that case is _use_ word, then pull in the word samples via `\includegraphics` or whatever.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Therein lies the problem—I don't have Word. :-)

Comment: LibreOffice would be a free alternative

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> no​​​​​​​​​​​:) – David Carlisle 3 hours ago

On the grounds of never say never, this builds the paragraph up line by line (with normal setting first)....

*update fixing small error in inserting parindent*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}




\makeatletter
\def\linebyline#1 {%
\ifx\!#1\else
\setbox\z@\vbox{%
  \noindent\unhbox\tw@\unskip\unskip\unpenalty\sporindent#1}%
\let\sporindent\space
\ifdim\ht\z@>\baselineskip
\setbox\z@\vbox{%
\unvbox\z@
\global\setbox1\lastbox
\unskip\unpenalty\unskip\unpenalty
\global\setbox\thr@@\lastbox
      \unskip\unpenalty\unskip\unpenalty%<<<<<
}%
      \ifdim\ht\z@>\z@\box\z@\fi%<<<<<
\hbox to \hsize{\unhbox\thr@@\unskip\unskip\unpenalty}%
\else
\setbox\z@\vbox{%
\unvbox\z@
\global\setbox\@ne\lastbox
}%
\fi
\setbox\tw@\box\@ne
\expandafter\linebyline
\fi}

\def\linebylinepar#1{{%
\par
\finalhyphendemerits\z@
\clubpenalty\z@
\widowpenalty\z@
\def\sporindent{\hskip\parindent}%
\setbox\tw@\hbox{}%
\@firstofone{\expandafter\linebyline#1} \! \relax
\box\tw@
\par}}
\makeatother


\kantdef\zz{1}

\zz\bigskip\linebylinepar\zz


\begin{minipage}[t]{.27\textwidth}\zz\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[t]{.27\textwidth}\linebylinepar\zz\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't do hyphenation, though.

Comment: @egreg yes it does! see line 3 and 4 of the narrow minipage for example

Comment: In the normal width example, `rep-` fits in the first line.

Comment: @egreg yes but I think that's not the spec, the idea is not to set every line as tight as possible and hyphenate as much as possible, it's to set the line to the _best_ setting possible with a look-ahead of just one word, in that case it's better to take the whole word over, you don't need the paragraph level optimiser to decide that.

Comment: Suggestion for long answer: "nooooooooooooooooooooo". `:)`

Comment: While I still have no idea *how* it does it (I'm going with black magic), this is *exactly* what I was looking for! (Although you're right, the only fair test would be to screencap/PDF-export Word's set and `\includegraphics` it, but this is exactly what (I think) word does!)

Comment: Would it be possible to make every line as tight as possible?

Comment: @pts probably:-)

Comment: I think I've found a bug in this implementation of `\linebylinepar`: some text disappears, see it here: http://pastebin.com/UNdSgJCa

Comment: @pts bug in my code? surely not:-) It's a design limitation it doesn't support words longer than textwidth (it assumes adding on one word never makes 2 linebreaks) it would be possible to make a loop testing for how many lines you have and taking it apart more carefully, or (more easily) warn if it is dropping text, but is there any real use case for this at all?

Comment: Yes, I was planning to use this code in production for typesetting narrow, multiline table cells if TeX's line breaking algorithm produces overfull or underfull boxes. A bugfix would be very useful for me. Without the bugfix I can't use it, dropping text is a no-go even with a warning.

Comment: @pts why not use the normal linebreaking? This was just an amusement to answer the OP's question of whether TeX could try to emulate a worse job. I may look, but probably not tonight, or I may not or you could post your code into a new question on site and someone else may want a go:-)

Comment: There is some input which normal TeX linebreaking can't break without an overfull \hbox, but this code can. Our input is 100000 table cells generated from a database, and we can't afford to manually fix all the failed line breaks, and we need an automated solution. I don't know of anything other than your code.

Comment: @pts that would be accidental. This code uses the same hyphenation points so does not have any additional break points.  For some particular text you may get lucky and this finds break points such that every line fits whereas the standard one fails, but if so that is (a) surprising and (b) with another text it could be the other way round. Just use the normal line breaking with a large value of `\emergencystretch` and you should be fine.

Comment: I need to gather more data on the success rate of normal line breaking (with a large `\emergencystretch`), to figure out how desperately we need an alternative. Please note that if we have an alternative, then we can try both, and keep the result without an overfull \hbox, or if neither has it, keep the result with fewer number of lines.

Comment: Please note that http://pastebin.com/UNdSgJCa demonstrating the bug doesn't contain any words that need more than 1 line break, so there may be another bug in your code causing text to disappear in an unanticipated way.

Comment: @pts the last big word causes 2 linebreaks one just before the word and one mid-word, the code only takes the last two lines so currently drops the top (3rd) line which is the line ending in allomas.  Compare the paragraph set using the normal settings

Comment: @pts still far from convinced you ever need this but I added two lines to fix the issue, see updated answer

Answer (score 8):

You can make TeX be not so fussy about consecutive visually incompatible lines, prefer hyphenation and be very tolerant about bad spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\adjdemerits=-1000000 % demerits for consecutive visually incompatible lines
\hyphenpenalty=-5000  % penalty added for hyphenating
\doublehyphendemerits=-1000000 % demerits for consecutive hyphens
\tolerance=10000 % bad lines are OK

\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here is another attempt. The third paragraph has been split manually with the “greedy” approach, taking into account `\righthyphenmin=3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\adjdemerits=0 % don't be fussy about consecutive visually incompatible lines
\hyphenpenalty=-5000 % prefer hyphenation
\doublehyphendemerits=-1000000 % consecutive hyphens are OK
\tolerance=50 % be strict as regards to spacing
\linepenalty=9999 % as few lines as possible

\kant[1]

\newcommand{\aline}[1]{\hbox to \textwidth{#1}}

\aline{\indent As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a rep-}
\aline{resentation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown else-}
\aline{where, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding.}
\aline{The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of}
\aline{practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would}
\aline{thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the Ideal of prac-}
\aline{tical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena. Necessity depends on,}
\aline{when thus treated as the practical employment of the never-ending regress in the}
\aline{series of empirical conditions, time. Human reason depends on our sense percep-}
\aline{tions, by means of analytic unity. There can be no doubt that the objects in}
\aline{space and time are what first give rise to human reason.\hfill}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first four lines agree, then TeX's algorithm takes on.

Comment: This is a great answer, but it's a bit too drastic when working with smaller `\linewidth`s.  Consider `\parbox{6cm}{\hyphenpenalty=-5000\adjdemerits=-1000000\doublehyphendemerits=-1000000\tolerance=10000\lipsum[1]}` (Oddly, the same does not happen for `\kant[1]`.)

Comment: don't you want the demerits to be 0 so you just tolerate rather than encourage incompatible lines?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Setting the demerits to 0 doesn't seem to have quite *enough* difference—only one hyphenation is added.

Comment: @SeanAllred but that's part of the problem with the whole approach rather than compare Tex to a typical word processor you have to compare tex to tex with settings where tex is not only not trying to optimise over the whole paragraph, it is trying to make things as bad as possible (over the whole paragraph) so it won't surprise anyone to find that the default tex settings make a better appearance.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree with you that no setting of the parameters will do as wanted and this can only be done manually.

Comment: @SeanAllred A small line width makes the task worse.

Answer (score 8):

> fit as much as you can onto one line, hyphenating if necessary, justify, and then move to the next line.

Here is a solution that completely ignores the hyphenation rules, and hyphenates as soon as the the line is full.

```
\def\greedybreak#1{#1\ifx#1\blankspace\else\discretionary{-}{-}{}\fi}

\setuppapersize[A5]

\showframe
\starttext

\input ward

\bgroup
\setupalign[normal,verytolerant,stretch]
\handletokens 
The Earth, as a habitat for animal life, is in old age and
has a fatal illness. Several, in fact. It would be happening
whether humans had ever evolved or not. But our presence is
like the effect of an old-age patient who smokes many packs
of cigarettes per day---and we humans are the cigarettes.
\with \greedybreak
\endgraf
\egroup
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

And here is the result with a slightly different test file.

[image]

The algorithm can be made slightly smarter so as not to hyphenate before punctuation :) (and using the `\dicretionary` command correctly; for now I'll leave the images with hyphen at the beginning of the line as well).

Comment: Super cool!! Is this answer ConTeXt-specific?

Comment: You can copy the definition of `\handletokens` from ConTeXt. The `\setupalign` part is just a wrapper around internal TeX macros (but much easier to remember!), so it should not be difficult to translate it into plain TeX or LaTeX.