# Greedy line breaks for 2 lines

Tags: line-breaking

I have some text to typeset which is short enough so that it fits to either 1 or 2 lines. I'm using `\raggedright`.

I'd like to set up parameters like `\hyphenpenalty` so that as much as possible would be put to the first line without creating underfull or overfull hboxes. If it is possible to hyphanate a word (and that would produce more text in the first line), then it should be hyphenated at the last possible position.

I was trying to change many settings including `\pretolerance-1`, but I couldn't make it work.

For example, here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\begin{document}
\hrule width137pt height 1pt
\vbox{\hsize137pt\parindent0pt\sf\raggedright\par
  Kun\-szent\-m\'ar\-ton, au\-t\'obusz-\break\'al\-lo\-m\'as \par}
\bigskip
\vbox{\hsize137pt\parindent0pt\sf\raggedright\par
  Kun\-szent\-m\'ar\-ton, au\-t\'obusz-\'al\-lo-\break m\'as \par}
\vbox{\hsize137pt\parindent0pt\sf\raggedright
  \pretolerance-1
  \hyphenpenalty1
  \exhyphenpenalty2
  \par
  Kun\-szent\-m\'ar\-ton, au\-t\'obusz-\'al\-lo\-m\'as \par}
\end{document}
```

, it's possible to fit *Kunszentmárton, autóbusz-állo-* to the 1st line, but if LaTeX is breaking the line automatically, then it only puts only *Kunszentmárton,* there (see in the last `\vbox`). How do I put as much as possible to the first line?

I know that TeX's line breaking algorithm optimizes paragraphs globally, and it's close to impossible to configure it to make it greedy, but maybe there is an easy solution when the text first to 1 or 2 lines.

I know about [Can I locally switch to a 'greedy' justification algorithm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131247/can-i-locally-switch-to-a-greedy-justification-algorithm) and `\linebylinepar` in its answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131275/820, but even that one wouldn't put *Kunszentmárton, autóbusz-állo-* to the 1st line.

Comment: fwiw, all your accented letters prevent hyphenation of the word they're in; `\usepackage{t1enc}` doesn't avoid the hyphenation effects of accent primitives; use `\usepackage{fontenc}` instead.  i suspect this hasn't any effect here, since you're not using hyphenation.

Comment: I don't need automatic hyphenation in this example, I've inserted all hyphens I need manually.

Answer (score 2):

Solving this is the main aim of the `ragged2e` package, see the added last example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\hrule width137pt height 1pt
\vbox{\hsize137pt\parindent0pt\sf\raggedright\par
  Kun\-szent\-m\'ar\-ton, au\-t\'obusz-\break\'al\-lo\-m\'as \par}
\bigskip
\vbox{\hsize137pt\parindent0pt\sf\raggedright\par
  Kun\-szent\-m\'ar\-ton, au\-t\'obusz-\'al\-lo-\break m\'as \par}

\vbox{\hsize137pt\parindent0pt\sf\raggedright
  \pretolerance-1
  \hyphenpenalty1
  \exhyphenpenalty2
  \par
  Kun\-szent\-m\'ar\-ton, au\-t\'obusz-\'al\-lo\-m\'as \par}


\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\vbox{\hsize137pt\sf\RaggedRight
  \par
  Kun\-szent\-m\'ar\-ton, au\-t\'obusz-\'al\-lo\-m\'as \par}

\end{document}
```