# Webpages that show off beauty of LaTeX output relative to `competitors?'

Tags: tikz-pgf, typography

There is a question ([Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends)) with many great answers showing off the great things one can accomplish with LaTeX.  There are books (like Tufte's) that provide dos and don'ts of providing visual information (mostly reducing ink to content ratio).

What are the best examples to show off the beauty of LaTeX output *relative to competitors*?  I'm aware of comparisons of line-breaking, etc, e.g. [Moby Dick](http://www.zinktypografie.nl/comparison.pdf).  Other great examples? (any feature)

Comment: I always find it weird that such a comparison document has the wrong zero numeral `O`

Comment: Compare an [engineering drawing made with latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/draw-an-aircraft-with-tikz/114847#114847) to the output of a typical CAD application.

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110133/visual-comparison-between-latex-and-word-output-hyphenation-typesetting-ligat

Comment: That question is only about typesetting text.

Comment: @percusse; I'm sure I'd like your comment if I understood it.

Comment: Look at the number zero in the document you have linked to