# How to tell if a document is written in Word or LaTeX?

Tags: msword, latex-misc

> [Readers] can tell at a glance whether the paper
>   was written using Word or LaTeX.

-- Graham Cormode. 2009. How NOT to review a paper: the tools and techniques of the adversarial reviewer. Page 2

I just read this and started to wonder, how exactly can one tell?
I only know that I could tell if our professor used Powerpoint or LaTeX for the slides, because the PowerPoint slides were scaled a lot bigger on initial zoom. But how to decide between Word an LaTeX?

---

Thank's for pointing to [Visual comparison between LaTeX and Word output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110133/visual-comparison-between-latex-and-word-output-hyphenation-typesetting-ligat). It does bring some good points, but that question is very specific in its aim. I want to find a broader series of answers, maybe not even related to visuals.

Comment: I'll redirect you to this very informative thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110133/visual-comparison-between-latex-and-word-output-hyphenation-typesetting-ligat

Comment: if you have the pdf to hand just look in the properties menu of your pdf viewer and it will tell you. If you mean just by looking on paper, then it's a matter of spotting typographical quirks of each system.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what kind of quirks are you thinking about?

Comment: Look at the linked answer.

Comment: Justification in Word is often a mess and the text look like a madman went in there swinging a cleaver.

Comment: linebreaking and math typesetting in tex are noticeably better, word math tends to use cambria, tex math tends to use computer modern Word documents can more easily have backgrounds and cutouts and other manually controlled design features and the text is less likely to be in computer modern.